# Frontend Ajax resubmits failed backend POST after error '500 The server failed to resume the transaction'

Tags: ajax, sql-server-2016

I have a Durandal frontend that uses ajax to communicate with a vb.net (servicestack) backend. On a particular critical route the stored procedure call is wrapped in a BeginTransaction, with a Commit on success and a Rollback on exception.
In one case I recorded the error:

> The server failed to resume the transaction. Desc:133000000db.

This error was trapped by the backend and reported to the front end (server error 500). The rollback presumably happened. My logs show that after the error the POST was resubmitted to the backend (presumably by the font end) about 10 seconds later, and this proceeded with no error and resulted in duplicate records (customer orders in this case).

So a few things: The rollback did not rollback the complete (if any) transaction, the stored procedure did not complete (there was a small bit at the end, setting a bit flag that either did not occur or was rolled back). And worst of all, the front end 'automatically' resubmitted the POST causing a duplicate order.

My question is about the resubmission of the post by ajax.  I do have a global ajax error handler that shows the user a message and records some info in a log, it does not resubmit the request.

Is there something built into ajax that would cause a retry of a failed post, maybe specific to error 500?, and if so can I turn it off?

Comment: Sorry, I put the incorrect tag, I am using sql server 2016 SP2.